# Alamofire POST request replacing characters in output

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am making this request:

```
Alamofire.request(path,method:.post, parameters:params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default,headers:headers).responseJSON { response in
print("Result: \(response.result.value)"
do {
self.list = try JSONDecoder().decode([list].self, from: result!) for event in self.lists {
print(event.title," : ",event.description)
}

} catch let parseError as NSError {
print("JSON Error \(parseError.localizedDescription)")
}
}
```

Data that ought to look like this (JSON?) - Postman output, all fields not included herein:

```
{
"start": "2016-02-01 11:30:00",
"end": "2016-02-01 14:42:24",
"id": 3192,
"ownership": false,
}
```

prints out looking like this in XCode:

```
{
start = "2016-02-01 11:30:00";
end = "2016-04-14 20:30:00";
"id" = 3192;
ownership = 0;
}
```

Result : I am not able to parse this using JSONDecoder, error:

> "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format".

Newbie to Swift ... so, thanks in advance for the help!

Edit: Edited for clarity with more information. Thanks again!

Comment: You do not show the code you are using to parse your response, please update your question accordingly. Also the output you provided does not look like proper JSON, it is already partly parsed through  the use of `responseJSON`. Please provide the raw string you get from `responseString`.

Answer (score 1):

Alamofire is not "replacing characters in output", it is giving you a *different object* than the one you expect. If you print out the type of your `response.result` you should be surprised by the `NSDictionary` you are likely to get at that point. Our trusted friend `print(...)` is nice enough to turn this into a `String` representation of whatever you pass it, but you are not likely to be able to parse this using `JSONDecoder` since it is *not* `Data` (which is what the decoder is expecting).

As I said before: use `responseString` in order to get the response and turn it into the appropriate `Data` for parsing using `JSONDecoder`. In order to be able to control this process properly you want to include your `Codable` derivative into the question and you are likely to set the date parsing strategy on the `JSONDecoder`.

Without your `struct` and some properly formatted JSON from your response (well, Postman will do if it is reasonably complete) we are unlikely to be able to help you any further.

P.S.: It is not an entirely good idea to change your question *completely* through an edit. You might be better of posting a new question and leaving a comment with a pointer to it on the old one so people revisiting it may be lead to the right place. If you update your question you should usually leave the old one intact and amend it with additional information in order to keep the existing discussion relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As workaround you can just add CodingKey to decoded struct. 
Just add to your struct/class

```
private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case event_id = "id"
}
```

Please refer to https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest the following solution:

> Firstly you need a pojo class to refer your json object. Easiest way
>   that I know is the library called SwiftyJSON
>   (https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) firstly you can add this
>   library to your project. Then you can create the following pojo class
>   for your output (**optional**: You can also install
>   SwiftyJSONAccelarator(https://github.com/insanoid/SwiftyJSONAccelerator)
>   to generate pojo classes using json outputs.):

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

public class MyOutput: NSObject {

    // MARK: Declaration for string constants to be used to decode and also serialize.
    internal let kMyOutputEndKey: String = "end"
    internal let kMyOutputInternalIdentifierKey: String = "id"
    internal let kMyOutputOwnershipKey: String = "ownership"
    internal let kMyOutputStartKey: String = "start"


    // MARK: Properties
    public var end: String?
    public var internalIdentifier: Int?
    public var ownership: Bool = false
    public var start: String?


// MARK: SwiftyJSON Initalizers
/**
Initates the class based on the object
- parameter object: The object of either Dictionary or Array kind that was passed.
- returns: An initalized instance of the class.
*/
convenience public init(object: AnyObject) {
    self.init(json: JSON(object))
}

/**
Initates the class based on the JSON that was passed.
- parameter json: JSON object from SwiftyJSON.
- returns: An initalized instance of the class.
*/
public init(json: JSON) {
        end = json[kMyOutputEndKey].string
        internalIdentifier = json[kMyOutputInternalIdentifierKey].int
        ownership = json[kMyOutputOwnershipKey].boolValue
        start = json[kMyOutputStartKey].string

    }
}
```

> After that after calling url with Alomofire and getting response, you
>   can simply map the output to your pojo class. Finally, you can use any
>   field in your class(myOutput in my example):

```
Alamofire.request(path,method:.post, parameters:params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default,headers:headers).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                let myOutput = MyOutput.init(json: json)
                //use myOutput class for your needs
            case .failure( _):
                self.createNetworkErrorPopup()
            }
        }
```